# Sparse submatrix re-indexing (scipy)

Tags: python, scipy

I've been recently dealing with the problem of submatrix construction under scipy. My problem is the following.

Let's assume we have a matrix A. I want to construct the submatrix B, such that the indices of the new matrix start with 0.

Example:

If I take some random subset of the A, I get something like:

```
  (20, 25)  0.0351988458293
  (9, 25)   0.0373496408275
  (4, 25)   0.0373496408275
  (3, 25)   0.0361027553258
  (2, 25)   0.0361027553258
  (20, 27)  0.258946282336
```

via this snippet:

```
subgraph = graph.tocsr()[idx,:].tocsc()[:,idx]
```

I would like the pairs in the left (indices) to start with 0. I can obtain this result by simply converting this matrix to a networkx object, and then using the "convert_node_labels_to_integers" method, but this is an ugly workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: These are the non-zero indices of the subset of matrix A, right? In that case, please post a more verbose example where you show how you are subsetting it and then getting this output

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added the code.